# Why are jpegs used for unsuitable images in many html emails

Tags: email, images, jpeg

I produce html emails on a regular basis in my work.

Recently I've been baffled by the number of promotional emails I receive which use jpeg for images which would be far better served by a png or even a gif.

I've attached some examples from big name brands in the UK: ebay, Cotswolds (an outdoor clothing company) and The Guardian. They all include images with large areas of flat colour that would show less quality degredation/artefacting and have smaller file sizes if they had been saved as a png. Cotswolds even have their logo saved as a jpeg!

**Is there a reason I'm not aware of that digitally savvy companies would use jpeg in these circumstances?**

As far as I am aware, png is well supported in all major email clients these days. I understand using a jpeg for a photograph - but not a logo.

[image]

**EDIT:** With regards to file size, it is a misconception that jpeg is smaller.

For image like these (with large areas of flat colour), **png will have a smaller file size**. Jpeg was designed for photographs.

I saved an image of this style as a png, and a jpeg at the lowest file size possible via photoshop. The png is only 13.7kb. The jpeg is 20kb. The png is around 30% smaller.

[image: JPG]
[image]

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about running your website.

Comment: "png is well supported in all major email clients these days" - I think you may have answered your own question. Yes, PNG is supported by "major [read: modern] email clients", but for _legacy support_ you may still need to resort to JPGs. Depends on your target audience.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a jpeg is smaller in file size. With a jpeg you can select the level of compression however this can sometimes degrade the image.

I only use png images when I wish the image to have a transparent background as it is lossless, therefore larger in file size. Using jpeg for for an image produces a smaller file meaning it is faster to load.

Comment: Agreed with Matthew, jpg is generally the goto format for optimised solutions not just on emails but on web too.  PNG's I tend to use for transparency or on images i require a greater quality for and the cost/size of the files don't matter

Comment: I have to disagree here. png and jpeg are designed for different uses. I have edited my post to include some pictures I created for comparisons sake. The png is 30% smaller in file size.

Comment: You can go much smaller with both file types in your comparison.  The PNG should be below 4kb really with no quality loss.  Like this : https://i.imgur.com/xLv7XJ3.png  

But you are correct images have different compatible compressions for file type usage.

Comment: You're not wrong when you say they could be smaller in png, this is why I state this is typically the case. Most people who produce content for the web will only be aware of the basics of compression. I would imagine they've used jpeg because they've been told that's what you should use for the web without knowing any fundamentals behind the technology.